# Generic Key Pool Factory setting parameters

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

How to set these parameters :http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-pool/api-1.2/org/apache/commons/pool/impl/GenericKeyedObjectPoolFactory.html

I have implemented a pool, now I want to configure various parameters[ mostly using a bean], but have no idea where are these parameters called, there seem to be no getters or setter for them

Comment: Have a look at http://www.androidadb.com/class/ge/GenericKeyedObjectPoolFactory.html and http://www.javadocexamples.com/org/apache/commons/pool/impl/org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPoolFactory.html you will get some examples of this api.

Comment: What parameters are you talking about? I see lot of constructors accepting various parameters which you can set through Spring constructor injection. Don't they suffice what you need?

Answer (score 1):

You would be using constructor args. Here's an example lifted from Spring docs:

```
<bean id="exampleBean" class="examples.ExampleBean">
  <constructor-arg><ref bean="anotherExampleBean"/></constructor-arg>
  <constructor-arg><ref bean="yetAnotherBean"/></constructor-arg>
  <constructor-arg type="int"><value>1</value></constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Comment: how does this answer link to apache commons pool?

Comment: It tells you how to construct the pool in Spring and how to format the values for the various constructors as documented on the page you linked to. You put then in the order the constructor needs them for constructor args. You don't use the setter methods that need names.